# invitation being called twice when sending

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-1.9

I have used `django-invitations` for invitation feature. I have used a form in homepage which asks for email address of the user. When user fills the email and hit the submit button. It is redirected to invitations/send-invite/ and again shows the form as in the screenshot

This is the homepage. I have filled the email address which has been never invited and whilst submitting the form, the page was redirected which is shown in second screenshot. The email has never been invited before but it still says it has already been invited 
[image]

[image]

Here is the configuration with the code

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^invitations/', include('invitations.urls', namespace='invitations')),
url(r'^accounts/', include(allauth_urls)),
```

**home.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'invitations:send-invite' %}" method="POST" id="invite-form" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" value="" class="form-control validate-email" placeholder="Enter your email address to request invitation">
        <span class='input-group-btn'>
            <input type="submit" value="REQUEST INVITATION" class="btn btn-primary generic-ajax-submit">
        </span>
     </div>
</form>
```

**settings.py**

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_INVITATION_DAYS = 7
INVITE_MODE = True
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'pages.login_redirect.AccountAdapter'
```

I have already `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` for allauth and I am confused on what to do with django-invitation's `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`.

Where have I done mistake? Did I miss anything?